# django: books doesn't like a module path

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning django. After using command "django-adimon startapp books" to start app books, and adding 'books' into INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE, I enter "python3 manage.py runserver".But I get a error like "books doesn't look like a module path".

How does this happen, and how to sole this question?

[There are my source codes](https://github.com/lucianosimon399/mysite).Error message is in the file [error.txt](https://github.com/lucianosimon399/mysite/blob/master/error.txt).

And my python's version is 3.5.2, my django's version is 1.10.0

Comment: You could add the relevant snippet of the error trace in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `books` from your `middleware` and it should work...! Any explanation why you added `books` in middleware ?

Comment: @Luciano that should be wrong! Can you provide me the link..? let me check

Comment: This course is in Chinese...Oh, I had accepted your answer just now, thank you very much.